# Can I Customize Square Appointments Booking Flow?

Tags: square-connect

We use Square to book appointments in our showroom. In an effort to optimize this booking page, I want to create a funnel and track clicks. According to their documentation it looks like the only way do this is via embed and I do not see anything about appointments in their [api documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/).

I really just want to track user clicks within the booking process and create some sort of conversion success page after the booking is complete. Any ideas?

Comment: I am also looking for something like this. It's pretty strange there is no way to inject a piece of JS on the booking page. So sad...

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do what you're looking for using the Square API. If you have access to the machine, I'm sure there's some way you could track clicks on the booking page (e.g. using a browser extension), but you wouldn't be able to make any changes to the Square UI.

Incidentally, Square is constantly making improvements to various aspects of the UI so that they will be more effective for all merchants. I do not personally know much about Appointments, but I expect that people are working to optimize it for you :).

Comment: Thanks for a great response. I actually love the entire UI for appointments, I just simply want to track clicks, so I know whether or not a user booked an appointment or not.